# Best way to find a line in MySQL by piece of value

Tags: mysql

Database:

```
+----+------------+
| id | somevalue  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 1000       |
+----+------------+
| 2  | 1001       |
+----+------------+
| 3  | 1002       |
+----+------------+
| 4  | 10021      |
+----+------------+
```

Question:

What is the best way to find a row by a string which contains piece of "somevalue"?

1. Let's say string is 1002123456. So in this case I must find row with ID 4.

2. Let's say string is 1002345678. So in this case I must find row with ID 3.

Would "MySQL LIKE" work in this scenario?

**UPDATE:**
Database has 60k rows and "somevalue" should be matched from the front. Because piece of "somevalue" might contain different rows, for example:

```
+----+------------+
| id | somevalue  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 1000       |
+----+------------+
| 27 | 371000     |
+----+------------+
```

I am looking for a way to make the process as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `db`.`table` WHERE 'someval' LIKE CONCAT('%',`field` , '%') ;
```

The RLIKE allowes you to match regular expressions in the fields

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated question. RLIKE doesn't seem to work in this scenario.

Comment: If you need to match from the front only, use `LIKE CONCAT(searchstr, '%')`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'searchNumber' LIKE CONCAT('%', somevalue, '%')